# How to set multiple tags to a button?

Tags: java, android

I have 16 buttons and I tag them to pair some terms set to buttons and imported from sqlite database. So, I tag them like this:

```
// labelForButton and tagForButton
       class MyStruct {
       public MyStruct (String lab, String t){
        label = lab;
        tag = t;
    }
       private String label;
       private String tag;
       }

mDbHelper.open();

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getSpojnice(generateWhereClause());

            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsA = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();
            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsB = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();

            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(2), "1")); // this tag should be the same to button that matches
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(3), "1"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(4), "2"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(5), "2"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(6), "3"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(7), "3"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(8), "4"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(9), "4"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(10), "5"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(11), "5"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(12), "6"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(13), "6"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(14), "7"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(15), "7"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(16), "8"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(17), "8"));

            Collections.shuffle(labelsA);
            Collections.shuffle(labelsB);

            a1.setText(labelsA.get(0).label);
            a1.setTag(labelsA.get(0).tag);
            a1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b1.setText(labelsB.get(0).label);
            b1.setTag(labelsB.get(0).tag);
            b1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a2.setText(labelsA.get(1).label);
            a2.setTag(labelsA.get(1).tag);
            a2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b2.setText(labelsB.get(1).label);
            b2.setTag(labelsB.get(1).tag);
            b2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
.
.
.
.
}
}
```

So, I need A1 and B1 to have same tags, also A2 and B2 and so on.

BUT, I also need for some other reason to all A buttons have tag for example "A" and all the B's "B". So, how to set multiple, in my case two, tags to one button?

EDIT:

I added this to my string.xml:

```
<item type="id" name="KOLONA1"/>
<item type="id" name="KOLONA2"/>
```

Then added tags:

```
a1.setTag(R.id.KOLONA1, labelsA.get(0).tag);
b1.setTag(R.id.KOLONA2, labelsA.get(0).tag);
```

Answer (score 28):

If you need to add multiple tag into one view then you have to define the id for every tag in `strings.xml` file like:

```
<item type="id" name="section" />
<item type="id" name="hide_show" />
```

After adding the key you can use these keys in java file like below:

```
rowView.setTag(R.id.section,mSectionList.get(position));
rowView.setTag(R.id.hide_show,"close");
```

This will set the tag.
At the time of getting tag you need to typecast the object which originally you set like:

```
String mSection=(String)rowView.getTag(R.id.section);
String isOpen=(String)rowView.getTag(R.id.hide_show);
```

Comment: This saves my day.

Answer (score 8):

You should use the [`setTag(int key, Object tag)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) method, which also takes a second parameter `key`. This will allow you to set multiple `tags` on each `Button` like this :

```
button.setTag(1,object1);
button.setTag(2,object2);
```

Comment: Yes, but how to implement that in my code when I have something like public MyStruct (String lab, String t) and later you can see how I use that?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can only give you hints & suggestions. I can not implement this for you.

Comment: I've added to my first post some code, can you at least check if that is OK?

Comment: This will throw illegalargumentexception.

Comment: The key must be an application-specific resource id

Answer (score 7):

try :

```
button.setTag(R.id.resource_id1,obj1);
button.setTag(R.id.resource_id2,obj2);
button.setTag(R.id.resource_id3,obj3);
```

and to get the tags, use

```
v.getTag(R.id.resource_id1);
v.getTag(R.id.resource_id2);
v.getTag(R.id.resource_id3);
```

but, this will return only objects. you need to typecast it.

Comment: illegalargumentexception

Comment: when you're getting the exception, while setting or getting

Comment: The key must be an application-specific resource id. A view can only have one tag!

Comment: Don't work.The key must be an application-specific resource id. In strings.xml you need add one item <item type="id" name="yourNameHere" />

Answer (score 1):

Define the key id in `strings.xml` and then get it through the id
example:

In String.xml declare the following code

```
<item type="id" name="date" />

<item type="id" name="name" />
```

now set the tag like following

```
 share.setTag(R.id.date,it.adjournDate);
 share.setTag(R.id.name,it.partyName);
```

Share is my button name

Now finally get the tag in button where you want these values listener like this:

```
v.getTag(R.id.name)
v.getTag(R.id.date)
```

Comment: Use it like this
<item type="id" name="date"/>