# Android Google Maps Marker Tag

Tags: android, maps, marker

Just a fast question. Is it possible to place multiple tags in a marker like this

```
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(getMarkerForUser(lat, lng, name, about, type));
marker.setTag(id);
marker.setTag(name);
```

if not, is there anyway to achieve this result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is **NO**

And if you want to set multiple tag [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911620/how-to-set-multiple-tags-to-a-button)

Comment: the link is not helfull at all. cause setTag in a marker only accepts one parameter which is object

Comment: ArrayList<>, Hashmap<> is also a subclass of object.

Comment: Yep i know. I already created a new solution for this and i guess your answer is correct so ill mark your answer as correct

Comment: Thanks. And Happy New Year